# line breaks when using ldots

Tags: line-breaking, memoir

I have a line in my novel which is not breaking in what I would think to be natural places. It appears to be due to my use of ldots:

```
``It was fine.'' she said, defensively. ``Just\ldots more and more\ldots   sporadic.'' She laughed self-conciously
```

The document class is memoir and I would expect the line to break naturally between \ldots and the following word but latex (pdflatex) appears reluctant to break at that point. It results in a very long overfull hbox (36pt too wide)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code set-up with this line included? I ran the line in a general case and the line breaks after ".. sporadic" and starts the new line with "she.." if the line starts a paragraph.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `memoir`

Comment: sorry to take so long to get back. @Leucippus, you are correct, the line breakes after the speech marks but with my set up this creates a very overfull hbox.

Answer (score 7):

There is no feasible line break point after `\ldots`

You can define your own version of dots with possible line break with

```
\newcommand{\bdots}{\textellipsis\linebreak[0]}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\bdots}{\textellipsis\linebreak[0]}

\begin{document}

``It was fine.'' she said, defensively.
``Just\bdots more\bdots and\bdots more\bdots sporadic.'' She
laughed\bdots self-consciously
``It was fine.'' she said, defensively.
``Just\bdots more\bdots and\bdots more\bdots sporadic.'' She
laughed\bdots self-consciously
``It was fine.'' she said, defensively.
``Just\bdots more\bdots and\bdots more\bdots sporadic.'' She
laughed\bdots self-consciously
``It was fine.'' she said, defensively.
``Just\bdots more\bdots and\bdots more\bdots sporadic.'' She
laughed\bdots self-consciously
``It was fine.'' she said, defensively.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Disregard the two overfull boxes, the point was to show the line breaks after the dots.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the \ldots command is eating the following space.  You can replace your \ldots with \ldots{}.

```
sample\ldots{} text
```

Comment: I'll bear this in mind. I'm surprised that ldots does not already allow a line break immediately afterwards... must be one of those typesetting traditions!

Comment: It's not a typesetting tradition.  It's the way Tex and LaTeX handle spaces after a macro.  It's not particular to the ldots command.  Enclosing the \ldots in brackets would also work - like this...  sample{\ldots} text

Comment: @susie I think actually this is the more normal setting, it differs from egreg's answer (and the code in your question)  in that it has a word space after the dots in the case that the line does not break at that point (+1)

Comment: more useful information! I've a lot to learn about LaTeX.